# clicking next button using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to automate installation of .msi, thanks Glytzhkof I got help to install.
Now I am trying to do the same using .vbs.
I need to press 2 check boxes, and for that I thought to give a try using .vbs
However, not sure how to do with .vbs
Here is the vbscript I have written:

```
    strComputer = "."
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run("msiexec.exe /i /path to MSI INSTALLDIR=/Path to install  /QB+ /L*V /log path")
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Need help with checking checkboxes, and finish button.

Regards,
Aman

Comment: VBScript is not suitable for that.

Comment: That depends on the actual problem. Answers may range from "use something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)" or "modify the MSI with something like [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/)" to "use a software deployment system".